# random module's randrange not working in pygame

Tags: python, random, pygame

I am trying to make a game in pygame and want to add apples at random places but the random module is not working. I tried looking online but the guy there was able to use this without any problem
**My code and The output is down below**

```
impoort pygame
imporrt random

pygame.init()

display_width = 1000
display_height = 500

gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width,display_height))
pygame.display.set_caption("SlikiSnake")

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
FPS = 15

block_size = 10

def GameLoop():    
    lead_x = display_width/2
    lead_y = display_height/2
    lead_x_change =0
    lead_y_change =0

    randAppleX = random.randint(0, display_width - block_size)
    randAppleY = random.randint(0 ,display_height - block_size)

    pygame.display.update()

    gameExit = False
    gameOver = False

    while not gameExit:

        while gameOver == True:
            gameDisplay.fill(white)
            message_on_screen("Game Over,press r to start again or Q to quit", black)
            pygame.display.update()
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type ==pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == pygame.K_r:
                        GameLoop()
                    if event.key == pygame.K_q:
                        gameExit = True
                        gameOver = False

        if lead_x >= display_width or lead_x < 0 or lead_y >=display_height or lead_y < 0:
            gameOver = True

        lead_x += lead_x_change
        lead_y += lead_y_change

        gameDisplay.fill(random)
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay,red,[randAppleX,randAppleY,block-size,block_size])
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay,blue,[lead_x,lead_y,block_size,block_size])

        clock.tick(FPS)    
        pygame.display.flip()
    pygame.quit()
    quit()

GameLoop()
`
```

but the error is:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/caaPn.png]

Comment: The code you're giving us is not correct. You misspelled *import* both times meaning your script should crash immediately, but according to your error it crashes at line 48. Your code is 82 lines but according to the error `GameLoop()` is on line 134. You haven't defined *white*, *black*, *blue* or *message_on_screen*. At one time you used *block-size* instead of *block_size*. DeepSpace gave you the reason to your error and he/she is correct.

Answer (score 1):

1. Next time write your code and errors directly in your question body, not as a screenshot.
2. You must have assigned `random` to a tuple somewhere between `import random` to the lines you posted.

Comment: hmm no I didn't and i edited my post so that you can see the entire code.

Comment: @ArnavKundalia The fact is that `random` **is** a tuple by the time that you get to `randAppleX = random.randint(0, display_width - block_size)`. Also, what do you expect the line `gameDisplay.fill(random)` to do, given that `random` is still the module that you imported?

Comment: What is the alternative for this problem..and also the gameDisplay.fill(**random**) is a color set by me in the program

Comment: @ArnavKundalia Then you must be setting `random` to that color somewhere, don't you? Make sure you are not setting it to a tuple.